# single sign in with azure

Tags: facebook, azure, acs

Using Azure ACS to sign in with facebook needs a developers app.

The creation of the app and adding it to acs identity provider is not a problem.
app id=390425354365693
app secret=7e9e9977160451dcadc9627abcf4f116

My site redirects to the login option screen, and the login screen redirects to https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=390425354365693&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2facsnils.accesscontrol.windows.net%2fv2%2ffacebook%3fcx%3dcHI9d3NmZWRlcmF0aW9uJnJtPWh0dHAlM2ElMmYlMmYxMjcuMC4wLjElM2E4MSUyZiZjeD1ybSUzZDAlMjZpZCUzZHBhc3NpdmUlMjZydSUzZCUyNTJmJmlwPUZhY2Vib29rLTM5MDQyNTM1NDM2NTY5Mw2&scope=email
when opting for "sign in with facebook".

now my facebook app has to accept my site 127.0.0.1:81/
and/or? single sign in page https://acsnils.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/wsfederation?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=http%3a%2f%2f127.0.0.1%3a81%2f&wctx=rm%3d0%26id%3dpassive%26ru%3d%252f&wct=2012-12-05T09%3a02%3a36Z

This means I have to add these sites, but I can't seem to find out how.
Which steps do I need to take?

Answer (score 1):

If you go into the old portal https://windows.azure.com

- Click on "Service Bus, Access Controls and Caching"
- Select "Access Control" and your ACS service
- Click "Access Control Service" button on the top ribbon
- On the left-hand side you can see "Relying party applications"

In there you can add new ones for development, testing, production etc. with different URLs as well: 127.0.0.1:81/, localhost:6700, test.mydomain.com etc.

Comment: this is for the azure part, what I was missing was the facebook part.
1) EDIT APP
2) look For :Select how your app integrates with Facebook
3) Click on: Website met Facebook-aanmelden
4) add the used acs site url like this to let facebook accept your acs: https://acsnilstemplate.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/facebook